# How to bring spinner arrow closer to selected text?

Tags: android, android-layout, spinner, android-spinner

I know this question is repeated but I don't get the Proper solutions.
  I want to bring arrow closer to the Spinner (That means i want to decrease the width of spinner and decrease the space between text and down arrow) I have used default spinner. How can I do that? Please, guide me to get Solution.
  Here is the XML code

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/relativeLayout15">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/languageDropdown"
            style="@style/SpinnerTheme"
            android:layout_width="66dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:entries="@array/Languages" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please specify your problem clearly.

Comment: That means you want to decrease the width of spinner and decrease the space between text and down arrow, right ? I edited your question.

Comment: How to change the Font style of defult spinner?

Answer (score 0):

As i am understanding your question, many time we face requirement to customise spinner UI and it is too tough to achieve this. I generally use this solution for such situations:

**Solution:** Hide your actual `Spinner` and show a `TextView` which just looks like our desired `Spinner`, Please have a look at below image for better understanding:

[image]

In above image I have created a phone number field where I am getting country code from user using `Spinner`. I created a `TextView` having text as country code with drawable[right] of down arrow. Please check below XML code for better understanding:

[image]

In above image `Spinner` width is `0dp` so your `Spinner` will not be visible. **Just remember one thin you have to handle click event of `TextView` and call `performClick()` method for `Spinner`**. Please refer below image for this code:

On the click event of your `TextView`, just follow below way:

```
textViewLabelCodeRegister.id -> {
   spinnerCountriesRegister.performClick()
}
```

That's It.

Comment: How to change the font style of default spinner?

Answer (score 0):

Make **PopupWindow** instead of **Spinner**.